# Деструктуризация массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть массив строк, в котором возможно есть еще один массив со строками и так далее. В результате мне нужно получить одномерный массив со строками из всех массивов. Вот пример кода

```js
const data = ["str1", "str2", ["str1", ["str1", "str2"], "str2"], "str3"]
```

В результате должно получится

```js
["str1", "str2", "str1", "str1", "str2", "str2", "str3"]
```

Я не понимаю как правильно сделать деструктуризацию

```js
const data = ["str1", "str2", ["str1", ["str1", "str2"], "str2"], "str3"]
console.log(data.filter((s) => s).map((s) => (typeof s === "string" ? s : [...s])))
```

Comment: mdn [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: `data.flat(Infinity)`

Comment: с каких пор у нас методы даже не из черновиков в комменты пишут?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const data = ["str1", "str2", ["str1", ["str1", "str2"], "str2"], "str3"];
let d1 = data;
let count = 0;
while (count != d1.length) {
  count = d1.length;
  d1 = d1.flat();
}
console.log(d1);
```

Comment: Что если вложенный массив будет содержать всего один элемент - массив с несколькими элементами? Тогда при "уплощении" на один уровень количество элементов не изменится и цикл прекратится...

Comment: Ну и зачем эту муть писать?

Comment: @Leonid Нет, это я.

Answer (score 4):

Можно тоже одной строкой и рабочий вариант.

```js
let data = ["str1", "str2", [["str1", ["str1", "str2"], "str2"]], "str3"];

while (data.some(item => Array.isArray(item))) data = data.flat();

console.log(data);
```

Продолжая тему разных побочных эффектов: метод `.toString()` для массива полностью "уплощает" массив, выводя стоку с элементарными значениями, разделенную запятыми. Эту строку можно так же методом `.split()` преобразовать обратно в массив. Понятно, что при этом объекты и прочие сложные данные утрачиваются, но для строк и чисел подходит.
Метод `.filter()` добавил из-за присутствия пустых квадратных скобок, образующих пустые элементы.

```js
  let arr = ["str1", "str2", [], [[]], [["str1", ["str1", "str2"]], "str2"], "str3"];

  console.log(arr.toString().split(',').filter(el => el!==''));
```

Comment: Зачем? Чем нормальный вариант не угодил?

Comment: @Qwertiy тут приводили сложные варианты с JSON, а это, на мой взгляд, проще. Кроме того, интересен сам побочный эффект `arr.toString()` - получается, что он удаляет любую вложенность и это надо иметь в виду при его использовании, мне кажется. А вообще ваш вариант, конечно, самый правильный)) Просто `Infinity` - как-то страшно и необъятно))

Answer (score 3):

Да никак её не делать:

```js
const data = ["str1", "str2", ["str1", ["str1", "str2"], "str2"], "str3"]
console.log(data.flat(Infinity))
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант для любой вложенности массивов, полностью стандартный (без использования экспериментальных методов), без рекурсии, и главное - забавный:

```js
const foo = arr => /[^\\]{/.test(
  arr = JSON.stringify(arr)
    .replace(/([^\\])(\[|\])+/g, '$1').replace(/,(\s*,)+/g, ',') + ']'
) ? null : JSON.parse(arr); 

console.log('Массив из вопроса: ',
  foo(["str1", "str2", ["str1", ["str1", "str2"], "str2"], "str3"])
); 
console.log('"Усложненный" массив: ',
  foo(["str1", "str2", [], [[]], [["str1", ["str1", "str2"]], "str2"], "str3"])
);
```

Недостаток: отсутствие обработки циклических ссылок.

---

<sub>// Готов к минусам за этот ответ</sub>

Comment: `console.log(foo(["str1", "str2", [["str1", ["str1", "str2"]], "str2"], "str3"]));` так опять не работает. Минусы ставлю не я)))

Comment: хороший пример как делать **НЕ** нужно. 
PS минус не мой :)

Comment: @Leonid, спасибо за верное замечание! Исправил, дополнил чуть более сложным случаем))

Comment: @Swartex, в прод коде - согласен, такое было бы довольно ужасно (как раз поэтому и готов к минусам, не против их получения). Но помимо решения рабочих задач, бывают и другие разные случаи. Ответ всего лишь показывает пример необычного подхода, и (надеюсь) мотивирует кого-то _думать_ о всяких таких безумствах, даже не применяя их, потому что мышление за рамками - это не так уж плохо))

Comment: Теоретически массив может содержать строку вида `'str1[abcd[[___]}'`, тогда все скорее всего сломается))) Нет, все нормально, не ломается, проверено!

Comment: @Leonid, от таких строк вроде не ломается. Но вот последовательности типа `]]]` из строк пропадают, это да - есть такой недостаток у "исправления" ситуации с `[["str1", ...`. Съедание лишних скобок конечно можно решить другим подходом к строковой замене (то есть, удалять скобки парами, вместо использования регулярок), но это уже будет чрезмерным развитием несерьезного варианта: таким путем можно и до ужасного вело-токенизатора докатиться в итоге)))

Comment: @yar85 обнаружил интересное свойство `.toString()` для массива выводить всё в один уровень. В продолжение вашей темы)) Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Leonid, это гораздо проще, чем через JSON (при том что недостатки в отношении потери данных почти одинаковы). Только передавать что-то аргументом прототипному `toString` массивов, не имеет смысла - этот метод не имеет параметров, и просто проигнорирует любое переданное значение.

Comment: @yar85 Куда пропал? Давно не видно...